# given the polynomial function find the function values

Tags: functions, polynomials

I given a problem and I can not get to the answer that I was given by my professor.

P(x) = -x^2 - x + 12 where P(-2). I keep coming up with 10. He gave me the answer of -2.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$p(-2)=-(-2)^2-(-2)+12=-4+2+12=10$$
So your answer is correct, assuming no copy mistakes.